# me gustaria resolver una cuestion con este problema, nose como pensarlo

Tags: haskell

estoy teniendo problemas con crear una funcion la cual me permite descubrir si un numero es la suma de dos cubos. La idea que tengo es la siguiente:

```
esSumaDeDosCubos :: Integer -> Bool

esSumaDeDosCubos n | n = (d+1)^3 + (d+1)^3 == True
                   | otherwise = False
                   where d = 1
```

pero me da todo tipo de errores, si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria. Tengo como consigna lo siguiente: que recibe un número natural n y devuelve True si el número n es suma de dos
cubos y False en caso contrario. desde ya, gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

La función que has programado no es recursiva y por lo tanto para todo "n" que insertes únicamente está evaluando si ese "n" es 16 (suma de 2^3 + 2^3).
Hace falta definir una función local que vaya aumentando recursivamente desde el 1 hasta que la sumaDeCuadrados sea mayor que "n".

Quedaría algo tal que así:

```
esSumaDeDosCubos :: Integer -> Bool

esSumaDeDosCubos n = aux n 1
  where 
    aux n m  | (m^3) + (m^3) == n = True
             | (m^3) + (m^3) > n = False
             | otherwise = aux n (m+1)
```